# How can I use the same CSS for 2 divs?

Tags: html, css

I have the 2 divs that I want styled the same. One is called #popover, the other is called #recordViewPopover. Here is my CSS for popover. How can I make #recordViewPopover use the same CSS as #popover?

```
#popover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: opacity 0.25s linear; 
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  cursor: auto;
  display: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  z-index: 5000000;
}

#popover > .popover_triangle
{
  border-top: 16px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-left: 16px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-right: 16px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-bottom: 16px solid black; 
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -34px;
  left:150px;
  width: 0px;
}

#popover > .header
{
  background: #222;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333 0%, #111 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55)),
    color-stop(0.2, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35)),
    color-stop(0.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)),
    color-stop(0.5, transparent),
    to(transparent));
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 27px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 -1px 0;
  text-align: center; 
}

#popover > .content
{
  font-size: 12px;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 190px;
}

#popover > .content ul
{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;  
  padding: 0;
}

#popover > .content ul li
{
  border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
  line-height: 25px;
}

#popover > .content ul li.item:hover
{
  border-bottom: #1443be 1px solid;
}

#popover > .content ul li h6
{
  background: #f3f3f3;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0 -1px 0;
}

#popover > .content ul li a
{
  display: block;
  padding: 0 14px;
}

#popover > .content ul li a:link,
#popover > .content ul li a:visited
{
  text-decoration:none;color:#333;
}

#popover > .content ul li a:focus,
#popover > .content ul li a:hover
{
  background: #5396e3 url('../images/arrow-small.png') 97% center no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .55) 0 -1px 0;
}
```

Here are my divs

```
<div id='popover'> 
  <div class='popover_triangle'></div> 
  <div class='header'>OPTIONS</div> 
  <div class='content'> 
    <ul>
      <li><h6>OBJECT VIEW</h6></li> 
      <li class='item'><a onclick=\"$(document).trigger('objectViewFiltersEnabled', [ !filtersEnabled ]);\">Filters</a></li>
      <li class='item'><a href=\"#\" >Configuration</a></li>
      <li><h6>OBJECT</h6></li>
      <li class='item'><a href=\"#\" >Configuration</a></li>
      <li class='item'><a href=\"#\" >Documentation</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </div> 
</div>

<div id='recordViewPopover'> 
  <div class='popover_triangle'></div> 
  <div class='header'>OPTIONS</div> 
  <div class='content'> 
    <ul>
      <li><h6>Information</h6></li> 
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Change Logs</a></li> 
      <li><h6>Actions</h6></li>
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Assign</a></li> 
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Share</a></li>
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Convert</a></li> 
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Copy</a></li> 
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Clone</a></li> 
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Merge</a></li>
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Refresh</a></li>
      <li class='item'><a href='#' >Delete</a></li>    
    </ul> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Use CSS selector grouping: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#grouping

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would assign them both the same class.  To do this you would have:

```
<div id='popover' class='someName'>

<div id='recordViewPopover' class='someName'>
```

and your CSS would be declared:

```
.someName {
//Add styles here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could [group](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping) multiple selectors:

```
#popover > .popover_triangle,
#recordViewPopover > .popover_triangle {
```

Or give the elements a class, and use a class selector where you have the id selector.

```
.popover > .popover_triangle {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#popover, #recordViewPopover {
    ...
}
```

Oh, and also

```
#popover > .popover_triangle,
#recordViewPopover > .popover_triangle {
    ...
}
```

But if you expect to have more divs like these two, it would indeed be better to define a class for them.

Comment: do I need to add #recordViewPopover to everything? for example: `#popover > .content ul li` would be `#popover, #recordViewPopover > .content ul li` ?

Comment: @SheehanAlam: Yes, if you go down this route.  If you have a lot of rules like that, using a class would definitely be better.

Comment: I am pretty new to the web, how can I combine all of this into the same class?

Comment: @SheehanAlam: See [m.edmondson's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650637/how-can-i-use-the-same-css-for-2-divs/7650650#7650650).